# Bayesian Classification for Text Author Identification

Tags: c#, .net, bayesian

I am interested in building my own text author identification system using C#. I am assuming that I will probably have to use some type of Bayesian Classification algorithm to accomplish this.

Does anyone know of any resources or existing libraries out there that do something similar to this?